# Show the following equality from Enumerative Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Let $f(m,n)$be the number of paths from (0,0) to $(m,n)\in N\times N$, where each step is of the form (1,0), (0,1), or (1,1). Show that $\sum_{m\geq 0}\sum_{n\geq 0} f(m,n)x^m\times y^n=(1-x-y-xy)^{-1}.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Try to construct a generating function using the fact that in each step there are three options with three distinct outcomes. And,
$$
\frac1{1-x-y-xy}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(x+y+xy\right)^i.
$$